# Is there a way to use the reddit API to get all the comments for all the posts in at once?

Tags: python

```
submission = reddit.submission(id="a3p0uq")
```

for example only takes one argument, trying to figure out how to get all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leverage [CommentForest](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/other/commentforest.html#praw.models.comment_forest.CommentForest) to pull down the comments.